# Eloquent sort table before join

Tags: eloquent

I have this Eloquent query:

```
        User::select([
        'users.name AS name',
        'order.name AS name'
        ])
        ->leftJoin( 'orders', 'users.id', '=', 'users.order_id')
        ->get()->toArray();
```

I need to sort orders table by id before passing it to leftJoin